# Где грамматическая основа в предложениях?

Tags: синтаксис

Детство - самая главная, самая важная часть жизни. (Я предполагаю, что детство - подлежащее, часть жизни - сказуемое).
Я за него жизнь бы отдал. (Основа - я отдал бы?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ изменён: Я бы сказала, детство - подлежащее, часть  жизни - сказуемое.

Я за него жизнь бы отдал. Отдать жизнь - фразеологизм, можно заменить одним словом "погибнуть" ( http://phraseology.academic.ru/8011/%D0 ). Значит, гр. основа "я жизнь бы отдал".

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В первом предложении я бы обозначил сказуемое словами "часть жизни", так как это неделимое словосочетание, а подлежащее, конечно, "детство"

Comment: Согласна,Lara, прошу прощения, часть жизни, действительно слитное словосочетание, как и " множество чего-то", меньшинство, большинство. Это у меня в голове, что это не фразеологизм.Учебная часть, санитарная часть,воинская часть, части речи, части света - фразеологизмы, а это просто неделимое сочетание в качестве одного члена предложения. Раньше их объединяли, а теперь разделяют.